# simple modals in a while loop

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to use a simple modals script to load different images base on rows on database. File name is same as 'id' column.

I understand that the div id has to be different each time it loop.

This is what I am trying to do

PHP part

```
$b = 0;

while ($data = mysql_fetch_aray($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$data['name']";
echo "<div id='basic-modal-" . $b . "'><a href='#' class='basic'>View label</a></div>";
echo "<!--modal content-->";
echo "<div id='basic-modal-content-" . $b . "'><img src='../winelabel/" . $data['id'] . ".jpg'></div>";
$b++;
}
```

jQuery part - from http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    return false;
    });
});
```

It only displays the image outright not in a modal. Also 'View label' is not clickable.
I suspect that I have to modified jQuery part but I don't know what to begin.

Thank you.

Jack

Comment: Note that the mysql extension is outdated and deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead; each has important advantages over the old extension, not the least of which is support for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in different ways. This is not best solution how to code, but I will show you some example.

I Assume that you does not use Jquery in Loop, never do that.

1. You can always detect Click event by Class and get ID of the clicked item, then do what you want to.
2. close  and  tags
3. `echo "<td>{$data['name']";` Close with **}** after $data['name']}
4. check Element Inspect -> Console what kind of error shows.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.basic').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#basic-modal-content-' + id).modal();
        return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Change it:

```
echo "<div id='" . $b . "'><a href='#' class='basic'>View label</a></div>";
```

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. I think I understand the logic. I need to learn more about jquery. Thank you.

Comment: I figured that you have one too many parenthesis and bracket. After I take one out, I got a reverse modal effect. Picture shows first but after I click view picture disappear from first page but reappear in modal. Which part of code should I be look at to fix it?

Comment: Ok. I solved it. Will show answer later. It has to do with css style.